# react js data is always display colmn wise

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

Hii guys Am stuck in react js in a small error please help when i am trying to display simple hello world program it will display column wise but i want it row wise ,, please tell me what can i do?

this is my output
https://ibb.co/3CN6zxM

```
import React from 'react';
// import '../Components/SidebarR.css';

const Sidebar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 style={{color:'white', marginLeft:'140px'}}>hello world</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code with below Css on parent-container `div` :

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
```

Link: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-jackson-c090x?file=/src/App.js:0-112)